# Give the series his respectives panes in a ChartControl

Tags: wpf, charts, devexpress

I have a problem trying to give the series his respectives panes. The three series appears in the same Pane. Do you need to do it in a different way when do you use SeriesItemTemplateSelector?

Error: Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=pane2'. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'AreaSeries2D' (Name=''); target property is 'Pane' (type 'Object')

```
<dxc:ChartControl Background="{StaticResource ControlsPrincipalColor}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ControlsPrincipalColor}">  

            <dxc:ChartControl.DataContext>  
                <vm:ChartViewModel/>  
            </dxc:ChartControl.DataContext>  

            <dxc:XYDiagram2D Margin="-68,0,-68,0" EnableAxisXNavigation="True" Background="Transparent">  

                <dxc:XYDiagram2D.SeriesItemsSource>  
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ChartModelConverter}">  
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource Graphic}"/>  
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" Path="DataContext"/>  
                    </MultiBinding>  
                </dxc:XYDiagram2D.SeriesItemsSource>  

                <dxc:XYDiagram2D.PanesPanel>  
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>  
                        <Grid>  
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                                <RowDefinition Height="200"/>  
                                <RowDefinition Height="200"/>  
                                <RowDefinition Height="200"/>  
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
                        </Grid>  
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>  
                </dxc:XYDiagram2D.PanesPanel>  

                <dxc:XYDiagram2D.DefaultPane>  
                    <dxc:Pane x:Name="pane1" Grid.Row="0">  
                        <dxc:Pane.AxisXScrollBarOptions>  
                            <dxc:ScrollBarOptions Visible="False" />  
                        </dxc:Pane.AxisXScrollBarOptions>  
                    </dxc:Pane>  
                </dxc:XYDiagram2D.DefaultPane>  
                <dxc:XYDiagram2D.Panes>  
                    <dxc:Pane x:Name="pane2" Grid.Row="1">  
                        <dxc:Pane.AxisXScrollBarOptions>  
                            <dxc:ScrollBarOptions Visible="False" />  
                        </dxc:Pane.AxisXScrollBarOptions>  
                    </dxc:Pane>  
                    <dxc:Pane x:Name="pane3" Grid.Row="2"/>  
                </dxc:XYDiagram2D.Panes>  


                <dxc:XYDiagram2D.SeriesItemTemplateSelector>  
                    <templateselectors:ChartAreaTemplateSelector>  
                        <templateselectors:ChartAreaTemplateSelector.FirstTemplate>  
                            <DataTemplate>  
                                <dxc:AreaSeries2D Brush="{StaticResource CorporativeColor1}" Transparency="0.7" DataSource="{Binding Values}" ArgumentDataMember="Date" ValueDataMember="Value"/>  
                            </DataTemplate>  
                        </templateselectors:ChartAreaTemplateSelector.FirstTemplate>  

                        <templateselectors:ChartAreaTemplateSelector.SecondTemplate>  
                            <DataTemplate>  
                                <dxc:AreaSeries2D Brush="{StaticResource CorporativeColor2}" Transparency="0.7" DataSource="{Binding Values}" ArgumentDataMember="Date" ValueDataMember="Value" Pane="{Binding ElementName=pane2}"/>  
                            </DataTemplate>  
                        </templateselectors:ChartAreaTemplateSelector.SecondTemplate>  

                        <templateselectors:ChartAreaTemplateSelector.ThirdTemplate>  
                            <DataTemplate>  
                                <dxc:AreaSeries2D Brush="{StaticResource CorporativeColor3}" Transparency="0.7" DataSource="{Binding Values}" ArgumentDataMember="Date" ValueDataMember="Value" dxc:XYDiagram2D.SeriesPane="{Binding  ElementName=pane3}"/>  
                            </DataTemplate>  
                        </templateselectors:ChartAreaTemplateSelector.ThirdTemplate>  

                    </templateselectors:ChartAreaTemplateSelector>  
                </dxc:XYDiagram2D.SeriesItemTemplateSelector>  

                <dxc:XYDiagram2D.AxisX>  
                    <dxc:AxisX2D TickmarksMinorVisible="False" TickmarksVisible="False" GridLinesVisible="False" Visible="True" Alignment="Far" Brush="{x:Null}">  
                        <dxc:AxisX2D.DateTimeScaleOptions>  
                            <dxc:ContinuousDateTimeScaleOptions/>  
                        </dxc:AxisX2D.DateTimeScaleOptions>  
                        <dxc:AxisX2D.Label>  
                            <dxc:AxisLabel Foreground="{StaticResource PrincipalForeground}"/>  
                        </dxc:AxisX2D.Label>  
                    </dxc:AxisX2D>  
                </dxc:XYDiagram2D.AxisX>  

                <dxc:XYDiagram2D.AxisY>  
                    <dxc:AxisY2D Visible="True" GridLinesVisible="False" GridLinesMinorVisible="False" Interlaced="False"/>  
                </dxc:XYDiagram2D.AxisY>  


            </dxc:XYDiagram2D>  

        </dxc:ChartControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, set the XYDiagram2D.PaneItemsSource property to generate the chart's diagram pane elements from a ViewModel and link them to the corresponding Series items.

Refer to the [How to bind a chart to its ViewModel](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-bind-a-chart-to-its-viewmodel-t541777) example that illustrates this approach.